# Find words from dictionary method. Performance improvements

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6

I've implemented a method to solve the following problem:

> Given a `dictionary` and a `text` string, find all words from the
>   `dictionary` that are present in the `text.` One important point is
>   that if the string is in double quotes, I should treat it a "single"
>   value. If no matches found, the method should return 0.

So for this input:

```
const text = `Hi. I am a developer. A "Hello world" program was my first code.`;
const dictionary = "hi developer world";
```

I should get this:

```
hi
developer
hello
world
```

**This is my current solution:**

```
const fn = (text, dictionary) => {
    const knownWords = dictionary.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    const words = text.toLowerCase().match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/gi);

    const result = words.reduce((acc, word) => {
        if (word[0] == '"') {
            const wordsNoQuotes = word.replace(/"/g, "").split(' ');
            const shouldInclude = wordsNoQuotes.find(word => knownWords.includes(word));
            if (shouldInclude) {
                return acc.concat(wordsNoQuotes);
            }
        } else if (knownWords.includes(word)) {
            acc.push(word)
        }

        return acc;
    }, []);

    return result.length === 0 ? 0 : [...new Set(result)].join('\n');
}
```

It works ok, but I would like to get some performance related improvements. I am happy to change the code (i.e using `indexOf` over `includes`) and so on. Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks.

Comment: *if the string is in double quotes, I should treat it a "single" value* This is a bit unclear to me, given the expected output example. Do you mean that if a matching word is included in double quotes, every word inside those double quotes should be matched as well?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, yes, if at least one of the words in quotes is in dictionary, all the of the words should be included in the returned result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main potential performance improvement I can see is turning the array of words into a Set of words instead. For every match in the string, you're doing:

```
const shouldInclude = wordsNoQuotes.find(word => knownWords.includes(word));
```

The `.find` is `O(n)` (it iterates over all words in the array, worst-case), and the `.includes` is `O(n)` (it also iterates through all words in its array, worst-case). So this is an `O(n ^ 2)` operation which is already inside a loop. That could be a bit expensive when either or both arrays are large. Using a Set for one of the arrays instead will allow you to use `Set.prototype.has`, which is an `O(1)` operation. The `else` part also uses `.includes`, which can be changed to `.has`:

```
const knownWordsSet = new Set(dictionary.toLowerCase().split(' '));
const words = text.toLowerCase().match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/gi);
const result = words.reduce((acc, word) => {
  if (word[0] == '"') {
    const wordsNoQuotes = word.replace(/"/g, "").split(' ');
    const shouldInclude = wordsNoQuotes.find(word => knownWordsSet.has(word));
    if (shouldInclude) {
      return acc.concat(wordsNoQuotes);
    }
  } else if (knownWordsSet.has(word)) {
```

```js
const fn = (text, dictionary) => {
  const knownWordsSet = new Set(dictionary.toLowerCase().split(' '));
  const words = text.toLowerCase().match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/gi);
  const result = words.reduce((acc, word) => {
    if (word[0] == '"') {
      const wordsNoQuotes = word.replace(/"/g, "").split(' ');
      const shouldInclude = wordsNoQuotes.find(word => knownWordsSet.has(word));
      if (shouldInclude) {
        return acc.concat(wordsNoQuotes);
      }
    } else if (knownWordsSet.has(word)) {
      acc.push(word)
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);

  return result.length === 0 ? 0 : [...new Set(result)].join('\n');
}
console.log(fn(
  `Hi. I am a developer. A "Hello world" program was my first code.`,
  "hi developer world"
));
```

But Sets have a small overhead as well, so while this will definitely be the best strategy for large inputs, it might do slightly worse for tiny inputs when there are only one or a couple of words. (But for such tiny inputs, performance is not an issue to worry about anyway)

You're currently pushing to an array inside the loop, then the array only gets used to create a Set to deduplicate at the end of the function. It would be more efficient to use a Set of the result words from the beginning, instead of using an array and converting to one after the fact (converting an array to a Set and the other way around is an `O(n)` process). At this point, since the accumulator would be the same Set every time, `.reduce` would [arguably not be appropriate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnZ7jMFCa4Y), so use a plain loop instead.

A potential issue in your current code is that if the global `.match` has no matches, it will return `null`, *not* an empty array (unfortunately). So, to avoid occasionally throwing errors, you have to check to see if the match exists first before iterating over it.

You're using `.find` to check if there are any elements in the `wordsNoQuotes` array which fulfill the condition. But you don't care about *which* element fulfills the condition - you just want to see if *any* element does. So, rather than using `.find` (which returns the matching element), it would be more semantically appropriate to use `.some` (which returns `true` if any elements pass a callback test, and `false` otherwise)

When the match is a quote string, your

```
word.replace(/"/g, "").split(' ');
```

iterates over and checks every character of the string *twice* - once to check for `"`s to remove, and again to identify the positions of spaces. Since you already know the positions of the `"`s are the first and last character, you could use `slice` instead:

```
word.slice(1, word.length - 1).split(' ');
```

But your `word` variable isn't necessarily a word - it may well be a quoted string which contains multiple words. To improve clarity, maybe call it `match` instead.

Edited version in full:

```js
const fn = (text, dictionary) => {
  const knownWordsSet = new Set(dictionary.toLowerCase().split(' '));
  const matches = text.toLowerCase().match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/gi);
  if (!matches) return 0;
  const resultSet = new Set();
  for (const match of matches) {
    if (match[0] == '"') {
      const wordsNoQuotes = match.slice(1, match.length - 1).split(' ');
      const shouldInclude = wordsNoQuotes.some(word => knownWordsSet.has(word));
      if (shouldInclude) {
        for (const word of wordsNoQuotes) {
          resultSet.add(word);
        }
      }
    } else if (knownWordsSet.has(match)) {
      resultSet.add(match);
    }
  }
  return resultSet.size === 0 ? 0 : [...resultSet].join('\n');
}
console.log(fn(
  `Hi. I am a developer. A "Hello world" program was my first code.`,
  "hi developer world"
));
```